# Error when adding Site Column to List - A duplicate field name "GUID" was found

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-fields

I am trying to add Site column(already created site column) to a document library but getting the following error : 
"A duplicate field name "b8581e64-01d1-4bef-9af9-06d190583664" was found."

Below is the code snippet:

```
 public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost:32155/sites/Test/"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (web.IsRootWeb)
                        {
                            SPListCollection docLibraryColl = web.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);
                            foreach (SPList list in docLibraryColl)
                            {
                                if (!list.Fields.ContainsField("Archivered Status"))
                                {
                                    list.Fields.Add(web.AvailableFields["Archivered Status"]);
                                    list.Update();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string msg = ex.Message;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Can someone help me to find why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

The field already exists in the list. It's possible that the same field is added to the list but with a different name. 
80% chance that this is the cause of your error.

You can use 'containsfieldwithstaticname' to check if a field exists by using the internal name of a field.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.containsfieldwithstaticname.aspx